# .is(":animated") vs stop()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

So this code does not do what I expect it to do, the stops do nothing and it keeps animating giving strange results, (because the calculation of newpos is wrong.

```
if (direction =='left') {
    newpos = parseInt(currentpos) - 300;
    $('.slider').stop(true, true).animate({"margin-left": newpos}, 1000, "easeOutQuart");
}
else if (direction =='right') {
    newpos = parseInt(currentpos) + 300;
    $('.slider').stop(true, true).animate({"margin-left": newpos}, 1000, "easeOutQuart");
}
```

But this works

```
if (direction =='left' && !$('.slider').is(':animated')) {
    newpos = parseInt(currentpos) - 300;
    $('.slider').stop(true, true).animate({"margin-left": newpos}, 1000, "easeOutQuart");
}
else if (direction =='right' && !$('.slider').is(':animated')) {
    newpos = parseInt(currentpos) + 300;
    $('.slider').stop(true, true).animate({"margin-left": newpos}, 1000, "easeOutQuart");
}
```

The question is how can I do it without the `is(':animated')` in the conditional? Should `stop()` do the job in this case?

Comment: If you can create a jsfiddle that would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
if (direction =='left') {
    newpos = parseInt(currentpos) - 300;
}
else if (direction =='right') {
    newpos = parseInt(currentpos) + 300;
}
$('.slider').animate({"margin-left": newpos}, 1000, "easeOutQuart");
```

Comment: you don't need to stop the animation, you need the animation to revert back from it's state so that you can do the reverse of the animation so i think you don't need the stop